# How to find out the smallest, biggest, average, sum of the numbers and numbers of numbers that are randomly enetered?

Tags: java

I am quite new in Java and I am asked to finish some certain tasks from my school.

1. I have to create a program where it asks the user to enter numbers (as many as the user wants)
2. But the entering number session will be stopped as soon as the user enters a negative number
3. And finally the program should print out the following (among the numbers that are entered by the user):

   - The smallest number
   - The largest number
   - The sum of the numbers
   - The average of the numbers (integer calculations are ok)
   - The number of numbers that the user entered

However, I was able to come up with the solution of 'Number 1' and 'Number 2'.
Now I need help to solve the 'Number 3' problem.

Here is the piece of code written by me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Please enter integer numbers, end with a negative number:  ");

    Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);
    int positive = numbers.nextInt();
    while (positive >= 0){
        System.out.println( "\nEnter a number:  ");
        positive = numbers.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println( "\nYou are done with entering number:  ");  
}
```

Last but not least,it's my first day and this is the first time I am asking for help here.Hope I was able to make a good impression about me and I am eagerly waiting for the reply. Again sorry for putting the code in a bad way.

Comment: Reading a java tutorial on collections would help you solve this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: @samlewis: Collections are not needed in this example.

Comment: Think about how your are storing the users input, think what will happen when each new input is added. Are you currently able to print out all the numbers once they are finished?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int total = 0;     // sum
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;   // highest
    int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;    // lowest
    int count = 0;     // how many nums enters
    int average;       // average
    int number = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        if (number < 0) break;
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();

        // for every number input, increase count by one 
        count++; // freebie code - complete the reamining [your code here]'s  

        // for every number increase total by number
        [your code here]

        // if number is greater than largest, largest equals number
        [your code here]

        // if number is less than lowest, lowest = number
        [your code here]

    }

    average = total / count;

    System.out.println("Total input numbers: " + count);
    System.out.println("Sum of input number: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Highest number: " + highest);
    System.out.println("Lowest numer: " + lowest);
    System.out.println("Average: " + average);
}
```

Comment: thank u peeskillet! what did u mean by "[your code here]"? Does it mean that I have to put that piece of code that I mentioned already?

Comment: See my answer, I gave you one of the answers you need, complete the remaining `[your code here]`. What ever logic you think you need, put it there. It can be more than one line of code.

Comment: peeskillet, Can u be more specific? what change u r asking me to exactly in my codes?

Comment: You don't have anything in your code that you need. So I'm giving you a template to work off of. Everywhere you see `[your code here]` replace it with some code that will represent the comment above it. I already gave you an example: `count++`. We do not give out complete code for homework here, so you must implement the code yourself. I'm just giving you the logic of getting the answers you need.

Comment: oh thanks a lot, I see, its midnight here, I will try that out tomorrow and will come back to u again with my code....

Comment: while(true){
        if (number< 0) break;
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        count++; 
        total++;
        if(number>largest)
            largest=number;

        if(number<lowest)
            lowest=number;
       }                                                                  I don't know if I have done it correct or not. And also it shows an error here: int number = scanner.nextInt();                                    It says that the variable "number" is already defined.

Comment: peeskillet, I can't put my code in correct way in my comment. It has only limited number of character left to give a comment.

Comment: You edit your post. There's a link at the bottom of your post to edit

Comment: Awesome! It works fine.  Can u explain the lines two below.           Why MIN,MAX_VALUE? Are they built in?                                                     int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;                                      And what does break statement do?

Comment: MIN, and MAX_VALUE yea are built in. They represent the min and max integer value.  You want to intialize `largest` with MIN_VALUE so that first number input will always be higher than `largest`, automatically setting `largest` to equals the first input. `break` exits the loop if input is less than 0