# Displaying the lowest number in Java

Tags: java

I have several days trying to figured out how to solve this problem, but I can't find the solution. I have tried all the suggestion but I still can't figured out how to display the lowest number.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;


  public class finalname {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("How Many Numbers You Want To Enter: ");
  int total = kb.nextInt();
  int input = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  int average=0;
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  while (input < total) {
    input++;

    System.out.println("Enter " + input + ". Operand: ");

                sum += kb.nextInt();

    if (min >= sum) 
     { 
         min = sum;
     } 
   if (max <= sum) 
    { 
     max = sum;
     } 



   average = ( sum ) / ( input);
}
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum + ".");
System.out.println("The avg  " + average);
System.out.println("The highest number  " + max);
System.out.println("The the lowest number " + min);


 }
 }
```

Comment: See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967209/how-to-find-out-the-smallest-biggest-average-sum-of-the-numbers-and-numbers-o/19967350#19967350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you `+=` `sum` ? If you are just trying to get smallest number from input numbers. Than change from

```
 sum += kb.nextInt();
```

To

```
  int n=kb.nextInt();
  sum += n;// += will sum your input. It is only need for average.

  if(min>n)// To get smallest number from input
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty close to working, but you are comparing `sum` when you must compare the actual number just entered.

Save the number to a variable:

```
int num = kb.nextInt();

sum += num;

if (num < min)
    min = num;

if (num > max)
    max = num;
```

After the loop, calculate the average.
Note: You should consider making `average` a `float` so you can display fractional results:

```
float average = (float) (sum / input);
```

Comment: System.out.println("Enter " + input + ". Operand: ");

                    int num = kb.nextInt();
                    sum += num;

   if (min >= num) 
  { 
    min = num;
  } 
if (max <= num) 
  { 
  max = num;
  } 

Got it to work! Thanks for all the help.